# What’s the default for new site in terms of hidden community?

Tags: support, wording, hidden-communities

[Hide community page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/wtf) contains the following phrase:

> New sites that you join will be linked to your other communities by default.

Is this phase correct?

As far as I see new site is placed into the list of visible communities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the behavior is as described by the quote. Perhaps a clearer way to say this is: "[Current site hidden] Note that any communities you join going forward will *still* be VISIBLE by default."

Comment: Is it possible to make phase clearer on the site?

Comment: @alexolut Not by me, but you can reword the question with your suggestion and change it to a [feature-request].